# Defining site on-topic scope in help center?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, scope, help-center

Closing votes because *"This question does not appear to be about DevOps, within the scope defined in the [help center](https://devops.stackexchange.com/help)."* are happening:

[image]

But the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page in the help center only has generic info:

> Please [look around](https://devops.stackexchange.com/search) to see if your question has been asked before.
>   It’s also OK to [ask and answer your own question](https://devops.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/self-answer).
>
> If your question is not specifically on-topic for DevOps Stack
>   Exchange, it may be on topic for another Stack Exchange site. If no
>   site currently exists that will accept your question, you may [commit
>   to](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) or [propose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site) a new site at [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), the place where new
>   Stack Exchange communities are democratically created.

Should that content be updated?

Comment: --"uploading images appears to be broken" probably because of the AWS outage...-- ok, strike that: [Is uploading images on DevOps broken?](https://devops.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12/uploading-images-on-devops-broken)

Comment: Image now uploaded. Thx for the reminder.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not yet. The scope of the site is still in flux; establishing what sorts of questions "work" here is something that time and experience does a far better job of than anything else.

For now, if you think a question is useful and somehow related to DevOps, ask it; if you see a useful question, answer it. We'll learn fast enough what topics *appear* on-topic but are not practical here, and which topics constitute the core subject matter of the site - those will be the material from which we'll eventually build the documentation.

#### See also: [Don't anticipate problems.](http://meta.devops.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-is-off-topic-for-the-devops/7#7)

Comment: Asking as someone mainly active on SO: should I "forget" about site-specific policies on SO and let this site determine its own set of policies organically? For example: tool recommendation questions.

Comment: You can't leave your memories at the door even if you wanted to, @Stijn. Instead, try to remember *why* we do things the way we do them elsewhere... And if you don't know, find out before you blindly repeat the rituals here. Tool recommendations are often useful questions, *but* they still need to focus on an actual problem *and the answers need to solve that problem.* The issue we were unable to overcome on SO was a long history of folks asking for the "best" library,   with aging answers and circling wakes of spammers trying to feed off of the rotting corpses; that doesn't *have* to happen.

Comment: Solid advice, thanks. It's easy to forget *why* we do things, after a while.

Comment: While this is all well and good I am a software developer and I'm not really sure what devops means. Its not a phrase I use generally and would generally class it as a buzzword rather than a technical phrase. The fact that it is the name of this stack exchange site suggests that I am wrong in this but it means when I get here (and I got here via a Hot network question) I have no idea what sort of questions should be asked here. Wikipedia seems to define devops though is pretty broad in what it suggests it covers. Shouldn't at least a rough statement of what this site is for appear somewhere?

Comment: I wrote this when the site was still in (early!) private beta, @Chris. It's likely high time for the *current* users of the site to be adding some guidance... But see also: [Do we need a question to define what is behind the term "DevOps"?](https://devops.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/do-we-need-a-question-to-define-what-is-behind-the-term-devops)

Comment: @Shog9 the future is calling back into 2017. 2.5 years on the world is still intact, but the old [What topics can I ask about here?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page as well ... the main point of [_my_ question](https://devops.meta.stackexchange.com/q/322/10715) is, however, why the close options for off-topic are so limited when there is no definition of on-topic. It's also perfectly fine for these definitions to evolve over time. Shouldn't the basics be there at least _for now_?