# Is uploading images on DevOps broken?

Tags: discussion, bug

I just tried to upload an image in a question on [meta.devops](http://meta.devops.stackexchange.com/) but it failed with:

> Failed to upload image; an error occured at imgur | Close

Is there something specific that needs to be set up for a new beta site for this to be working?

**Note**: it doesn't work on other SE sites either (just tried on SoftwareEngineering, same error.

Comment: S3's down in US - East, I wager that might be the reason

Comment: Can you try with different image (different type)? Does the same image uploads on other SE sites?

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't work on other SE sites either (just tried on SoftwareEngineering, same error).

Comment: IMO this question is a possible candidate for being closed ... It's aboot a problem (or bug or something) that cannot (I assume ...) be reproduced anymore, and therefor not a lot of value for future visitors of this question ... unless of course it repeats in the future.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I don't disagree, but do we have to do this now? It's not like we're running out of room for Q&As or anything like that. As long as the post isn't misleading or damaging in some way it can stay. I *might* even think of it as potentially useful: if someone runs into an image uploading problem this Q&A would offer a possible cause to maybe check out and/or maybe a better place to look, no?

Comment: Fine for me. You might as well consider it as an example of a Murphy-law situation .... anything that can go wrong, will go wrong, and it shall go wrong when it shouldn't go wrong ... I mean: bad luck that this incident (or whatever) happened around the time DevOps.SE got launched ... Also: what are the actual followup-steps taken by SE to prevent it from happening in the future, sounds like a DRP-topic (if you know that TLA), no?

Comment: Right. BTW Assaf's chat comment was golden: `Look how quickly I can clear this room.. [ahem] S3 IS DOWN!!! `

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens: DRP as in disaster recovery planning I presume. The accepted answer to the post linked in Robert's answer has a few notes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Amazon S3 US-East-1 is down. That is the cause of many of today's issues you may see around the network and the Internet in general.

Meta SE or the thread below is probably the best place to watch for updates:

[Intermittent Failed to upload image; imgur is rejecting the request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291609/intermittent-failed-to-upload-image-imgur-is-rejecting-the-request).