# Blatantly off-topic?

Tags: discussion, support

Uhm, I am not exactly the most active user here, since most of the stuff I do with any remote connection to devops will be catered by other SE sites (Unix, ServerFault, SuperUser and AskUbuntu come to mind).

However, when it's about [ansible](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ansible) I tend to think of this site and head here.

So today when asking an Ansible question of my own I noticed [this question](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/9546/10715), which I answered. However, the only connection with Ansible and therefore DevOps in the closer sense is that apt/apt-get/aptitude or whatever the Ansible `apt` module used in that case got executed via Ansible. The underlying issue has *nothing* to do with Ansible *whatsoever*.

So I decided to flag it and vote for closing it as off-topic. Alas, the dialog puzzles me a bit:

[image: Off-Topic flagging dialog ... choices]

The first two choices didn't seem applicable to me. This isn't about programming and even if this isn't reproducible (due to lack of information in the question) it would still not be a valid reason if the missing information were given.

Which leaves two options:

- **Blatantly off-topic** (this question has nothing to do with DevOps)
- This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

  - which in turn leads to "belongs on devops.meta.stackexchange.com" and therefore disqualifies the migration option entirely ...

So being a mod (pro tempore) on RE.SE I decided to double-check to see whether this question would be considered DevOps-related and ended up [on a page with the following contents](https://devops.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (at the time of writing):

> #### What topics can I ask about here?
>
> Please look around to see if your question has been asked before. It’s
>   also OK to ask and answer your own question.
>
> If your question is not specifically on-topic for DevOps Stack
>   Exchange, it may be on topic for another Stack Exchange site. If no
>   site currently exists that will accept your question, you may commit
>   to or propose a new site at Area 51, the place where new Stack
>   Exchange communities are democratically created.

Yes, that's *all* the content there is on that page other than navigation items.

The one piece of information which I'd expect to find on this page is missing: **what topics are deemed on-topic?**

So given the scarce selection of migration options when attempting to close a question, I am left wondering where to find a list of examples of items being on-topic or explicitly off-topic.

But I am also wondering why such strong wording (*blatantly* off-topic) is used, because as the only item that was not eliminated for other reasons, I am hard pressed to consider this [*blatantly*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blatant) off-topic, since the person asking the question is using Ansible which I would deem on-topic for a DevOps-themed QA site and even if Ansible wasn't explicitly included, one could still argue that such issue could reasonably occur in the daily routine of a devops staffer ...

Edit #1: admittedly I was shocked to find [this 2.5 year old question](https://devops.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11/10715) under related links *after* posting my question.